# CORS issue during AWS Cognito Hosted UI sign in using Google

Tags: reactjs, jwt, amazon-cognito

So I setting up signing in through Google on AWS Cognito. For the app client, I am using code grant. But the issue is when i am passing the generated code from `?code=1234abdce#$%` into the url in the following format:

```
let root_url = `https://<our_apps_domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`
let content_type = "Content-Type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded'&"
let grand_type ='grant_type=authorization_code&'
let client_id='client_id='+process.env.GOOGLE_APP_CLIENT_ID+'&'
let code_grant='code='+code+"&"
let redirect_uri='redirect_uri='+process.env.FRONTEND_URL+'/home'
let code_grant_url=root_url+content_type+grand_type+client_id+code_grant+redirect_uri

fetch(code_grant_url,{
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':process.env.FRONTEND_URL
        }
    }).then((res) =>
    !res.ok ? res.json().then((e) => Promise.reject(e)) : res.json()
  )
```

I am getting a CORS error: ***from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.*** What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html).

It is not a query string parameter. In fact, none of the parameters are to be passed in the query string. You should be using urlencoded body so just take your query string and pass it as the request body. Or better yet, `URLSearchParams` constructor to improve your code.

```js
fetch('https://<our_apps_domain>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        client_id: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        redirect_uri: `${process.env.FRONTEND_URL}/home`,
        code,
        code_verifier
    })
})
```

Additionally, since you are using a public client (a browser), you must use authorization code grant with [PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636).

Comment: How to use authorization code grant with PKCE? I am using Google signin, so it is through the Login endpoint INSTEAD OF the authorization endpoint.

Comment: @LearnerSamuelX Use the authorization endpoint. There is no advantage to using the login endpoint. You can automatically redirect users to google auth by setting the `identity_provider` request parameter.

Comment: with Cognito Hosted UI, I am getting automatically redirected to the /LOGIN endpoint.